# How to show query call back data results only start with

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

**Original code** :

```
var data = {results: []}
    data.results = result;                            
    query.callback( data);
```

original internet code for loading data :(Any modification to get start with data)

```
$("#e5").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    query: function (query) {
        var data = {results: []}, i, j, s;
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            s = "";
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {s = s + query.term;}
            data.results.push({id: query.term + i, text: s});
        }
        query.callback(data);
    }
});
```

Matcher function :

```
$("#e17").select2({
      matcher: function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0; }
});
```

Currently i am using this way :

```
      var $elem = $( ".auto{!randomJsIden}" );

        $elem.select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        placeholder: "No value selected",
        allowClear : {!allowClear},
         query: function (query) {
             queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);
        },
             createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
         if ({!syncManualEntry} == true) {
             return {id:term, text:term};
             }
            },
             matcher: function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0; },
            sortResults: function(results, container, query) {
             if (query.term) {
            return results.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (a.text.length > b.text.length) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (a.text.length < b.text.length) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });
            }
          return results;
             }
            });
------------------------------
------------------------------
 function queryData{!randomJsIden}(query){

           Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                     '{!$RemoteAction.AutoCompleteV2_Con.getData}','{!sObjVal}','{!labelFieldVar}','{!valueFieldVar}',query.term,
                     function(result, event){

                         //if success
                         if(event.status){ 
                            var data = {results: []}
                            data.results =result;                            
                             query.callback( data);                         
                         }
                         else{
          alert('Invalid Field/Object API Name : '+event.message);
                         }
                     }, 
                      {escape: true}
                );
            }
```

Currently i am getting result all if i type letter a it is showing results containing a,I would like to like show result starting with a.

Updating question :

```
 <script>
        var v2{!randomJsIden}
function permute(input, permArr, usedChars) {
    var i, ch;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
        usedChars.push(ch);
        if (input.length === 0) {
            permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
        }
        permute(input, permArr, usedChars);
        input.splice(i, 0, ch);
        usedChars.pop();
    }
    return permArr;
}
        var prevVal{!randomJsIden};
        function autocompleteV2{!randomJsIden}(){
             var v2=this;
             jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
                    v2.init($)
             });
        }

        autocompleteV2{!randomJsIden}.prototype={
            init : function($){

                       var $elem = $( ".auto{!randomJsIden}" ).select2({
                           minimumInputLength: 3,
                           placeholder: "No value selected",
                           allowClear : {!allowClear},
                           query: function (query) {
                               queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);

                           },
                           createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
                                if({!syncManualEntry} == true){
                                    return {id:term, text:term};
                                }
                            },
                            matcher: function (term, text) {

        if (term.length === 0) return true;
        texts = text.split(" ");

        allCombinations = permute(texts, [], []);

        for (i in allCombinations) {
            if (allCombinations[i].join(" ").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) === 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    sortResults: function (results, container, query) {
        if (query.term) {
            // use the built in javascript sort function
            return results.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.text.length > b.text.length) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (a.text.length < b.text.length) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });
        }
        return results;
    }

                       });

                       $elem.on("select2-selecting", function(e) {

                           $('.hiddenField{!randomJsIden}').val(e.val);
                       });

                       $elem.on("select2-removed", function(e) {
                           $('.hiddenField{!randomJsIden}').val('');
                       });



                       if('{!cacheField}' !=''){
                           $elem.select2("data", {id: "{!targetFieldVar}", text: "{!cacheField}"})  
                       }  

                    },

            triggerSearch :function(val){

                                if(prevVal{!randomJsIden} != val){
                                    $=jQuery;
                                    prevVal{!randomJsIden} = val;
                                    var select = $('input.auto{!randomJsIden}');          
                                    var search = $('.select2-input')
                                    select.select2('open');
                                    search.val(val);

                                    search.trigger("input");
                                }
                            }
        }





         /*
        *This method queries data according to the passed parameter
        *and populates the combobox accordingly
        ***/    
        function queryData{!randomJsIden}(query){

           Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                     '{!$RemoteAction.AutoCompleteV2_Con.getData}','{!sObjVal}','{!labelFieldVar}','{!valueFieldVar}',query.term,
                     function(result, event){

                         //if success
                         if(event.status){ 
                             var data = {results: []}
                             data.results = result;                            
                             query.callback( data);                           
                         }
                         else{
                              alert('Invalid Field/Object API Name : '+event.message);
                         }

                     }, 
                      {escape: true}
                );
            }  


    </script>

    <apex:inputText style="{!Style}" id="hiddeninput" styleClass="auto{!randomJsIden}" value="{!cacheField}" />

    <apex:outputPanel id="hiddenPanel">
        <apex:inputText value="{!targetField}" id="hiddenField"
            styleClass="hiddenField{!randomJsIden}" style="display:none"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <script>v2{!randomJsIden} = new autocompleteV2{!randomJsIden}({});</script>
</apex:component>
```

Still cant able to get result .I am using latest version from select2 3.5.4 please help me regarding this .

Help me regarding this .

Updating my question :

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnf8j/289/

i experimented with this fiddle :

```
$('#placeSelect').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Ford"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Dodge"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Mercedes" },
            { id: 4, text: "Jaguar"   }
          ],
     matcher: function (term, text) {

           if (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
});
```

i am getting good results

if i changed this to data by this

```
   query: function (query) {
    queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);
            },
         (OR)             


 var data = {results: []}
data.results = result;                            
query.callback( data);
```

I am not getting good result 
some thing to change here to get good result

Answer (score 1):

Change your matcher function accordingly something like this:

```
  matcher: function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().startsWith(term.toUpperCase()); }
```

Comment: still i can see remaining i mean type "acccount" it shows account1,account2,account3,test account .

Comment: I think you may be using an older version of select2. Matcher is available in 4.0.0 version and higher https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#new-matcher the older version has no matcher so your matcher function may not have been called.

Comment: Still i am not getting result Could you please help me regarding this please .

Comment: I am using latest select2 3.5.4 version this is latest one which genearted by apache . I will update my question .Please help me

Comment: See select2 matcher works in 4+ version you are using 3.5 which is old. Please pick the latest from cdn https://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2

Comment: I dont see functions of select2-selecting,select2-removed,createSearchChoice any function on this 4+ version .

Comment: https://github.com/select2/select2/tags  .you can in the above link 3.5.4 is different form 4.0.2,4.0.1  files are different every thing is different

Comment: please read the update of my question .Let me know any possible help you can do

Answer (score 1):

Change your matcher function (aka your "predicate") to test only the first character in `text`. There are a few ways to do this, but I think the best is to use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). A regular expression is a type of search term that you can use on strings. In this case, you might use a RegExp like `term = /^a/i`:

- `/`: Start the regular expression.
- `^`: This regular expression only matches at the beginning of the text.
- `a`: The regular expression succeeds if it sees a literal character `a` at the immediate beginning of the text (since we wrote `^`).
- `/`: End the regular expression.
- `i`: The regular expression is case *in*-sensitive; it can match `A` or `a`.

This function will return true if a RegExp object `term` matches a string `text`:

```
function matcher(term, text) {
    if (text.match(term)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of `return matcher(term, text))`, you could just write `return text.match(term)` from then on. But beware that a positive result isn't just a `true` value (see the documentation of [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)).

Comment: Still i am not getting result Could you please help me regarding this please .

Comment: I am using latest select2 3.5.4 version this is latest one which genearted by apache . I will update my question .Please help me